# Альтернативный прием запроса Post

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, у меня есть форма, в которой 4 поля, в обработчике обрабатываю их так

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name= $_POST['name']; if ($name == '') {unset($name);}}  
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {$id= $_POST['id']; if ($id== '') {unset($id);}}  
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {$text= $_POST['text']; if ($text== '') {unset($text);}}  
if (isset($_POST['description'])) {$description= $_POST['description']; if ($description== '') {unset($description);}}
```

И получается сильно большой код, можно ли как-нибудь принимать Post запросы иначе?
А то запросов может быть и больше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Например:

```
$varnames = array('name','id','text','description');  
foreach($varnames as $varname){  
  if(!empty($_POST[$varname])){//нет смысла создавать переменную, а потом ее уничтожать. Лучше сразу проверить на наличие значения и НЕ создавать, если оно пустое  
    $$varname = $_POST[$varname]; //Обратите внимание на двойной доллар  
  }  
}
```

P.S. если этот кусок кода где-то в середине и нет уверенности, что указанные переменные не были созданы ранее, можно чуть изменить цикл:

```
foreach($varnames as $varname){  
      if(isset($$varname)) unset($$varname);
      if(!empty($......
```

Comment: уничтожаю я ее потому что, делаю проверку isset() если существует то {
//действие
}  
сейчас буду разбирать способы,и выберу более подходящий способ и ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```
function gv (&$v, $alt = false) { return (!empty($v)) ? $v : $alt; }
$err = 0;
foreach (array('name', 'id', 'text', 'description') as $v)
  if (!$$v = gv($_POST[$v])) $err++;
```

Comment: Бррр... Еле врубился более-менее что к чему. Не очень ясно только зачем передавать пост по ссылке. Поясните?

Comment: потому что $_POST['id'] может не существовать, это *`Warning: undefined index`*. Кстати, лучше даже объявить `$err` как массив и вместо `$err++` использовать `$err[]=$v;`, будет доступно поле с ошибкой.

Comment: Прикольно, про это свойство ссылки не знал. Всегда empty использовал.

Comment: Так empty тоже ссылку принимает, только булев результат возвращает. Функция выше удобна дефолтным значением (второй аргумент). <pre> $articleName = gv($_POST['name'], 'Не указано'); // как-то так) </pre>

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, можно сделать еще короче. Можно, попробуйте воспользоваться

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) { if($value!='') $key=$value; }
```

Comment: Можно. Но тут есть такая подлянка: злоумышленник сможет через это изменить ЛЮБУЮ переменную в коде - теряется смысл создания суперглобального массива, как средства защиты от инъекций. А это не есть хорошо.  
В моем примере изменять можно только заранее оговоренные переменные, что несколько повышает безопасность.

Comment: Вообще мне кажется лучше каждый POST  принимать отдельно и фильтровать.     думаю все равно будет заведомо известно сколько POST будет. допустим мы прогоним через массив. мы не узнаем какие переменные создались. т.е. потом далее в коде опять придется делать проверку, или использовать @$var для подавления ошибок. лично я фильтрую каждое значение отдельно, для каждой свои условия( одни могут содержать только числа и т.д.). Да, код чуть больше, но зато  сразу все видно и не надо по 100 раз делать одно и тоже. А код привел лишь как пример.

Comment: Тут вы не правы. =) Думаю, вам уже приходилось(или еще придется) сталкиваться с универсальными функциями обработки форм.   
Поля формы, в норме, забираются из БД(а не указаны в массиве, как у меня).  
После чего функция проверяет допустимый диапазон значений для поля(тоже берется из ЮД) и отправляет его в функцию компиляции запроса к базе.
"голые" переменные, конечно, не нужны, но принцип остается тот же: разорить пост, выцепить нужные переменные(а не все, что накидал гуманойд на том конце провода), проверить их и отправить на дальнейшую обработку.

Comment: Насчет универсальных функций- не могу знать как сделано у автора поста. может вся обработка у него заключается лишь в создании переменных и отсылке их в запрос. Тогда если как Вы говорите, да, легче создавать массив  допустимых переменных, если же  названия переменных идентичны полям бд, то думаю стоит вытягивать их сначала при помощи запроса(чтобы каждый раз как поправил бд не лезть в пхп).

Comment: Как правило, названия НЕ идентичны названиям полей. Для все той же секьюрности. В БД хранится таблица-словарь, которая преобразует названия.  
В любом случае, стоит побеспокоиться о безопасности.  
Кстати, ХэшКод(?) промахнулся при правке:  

    if($value!='') $key=$value;

Тут нужен тот же двойной доллар.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
$arr=array();
$result=array();
$arr=$_POST;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
   $result[$key] = $value;
}
```

ну и потом обрабатывать массив $result

Comment: Это уже лучше. =) Но... вы поменяли шило на мыло. =) Был массив пост, стал массив резалт. Все равно указанные "голые" переменные какими были, такими и остались.